# angular issue in scss file

Tags: css, angular, sass

Below is my css file. After updating to angular 11 , if i include last 2 rows am getting below error ..

styles.css

```
@import '~simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css';
@import '~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css';
@import '~ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css';
   
@import '~ngx-toastr/toastr-bs4-alert';    --if i add this am getting beow error
@import '~@coreui/coreui/scss/coreui';    --if i add this am getting beow error
```

Error

Error: ./src/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
╷
63 │     @include border-radius($alert-border-radius);
│     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
node_modules\ngx-toastr\toastr-bs4-alert.scss 63:5  @import
src\styles.scss 6:9                                 root stylesheet
at E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
at E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:56:7
at Function.call$2 (E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:89862:16)
at _render_closure1.call$2 (E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:79036:12)
at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:26612:18)
at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25140:19)
at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25437:49)
at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:4502:77)
at _Future._completeError$2 (E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25270:9)
at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24613:12)
at Object._asyncRethrow (E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:4251:17)
at E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:13112:20
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.UI\cps\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:4276:15)

Am using anglar 11 projects..Pls any one suggest

Answer (score 1):

Install "css-loader": "^2.1.0"

```
npm i css-loader
```

Comment: Thanks ..but again i am getting error..updated in question..